# Can't run explorer.exe properly

Tags: winapi, explorer, autohotkey

I play some older games that require ending the process `explorer.exe`. This is fine, except I want a way to start `explorer.exe` back up when I am done playing. I thought to use this:

```
^#e::
    Run, explorer.exe
    Return
```

The weird thing is that when I run this, it opens one window in the "Libraries". However, when I open the task manager and `Start new process --> explorer.exe`, then everything comes back (desktop, taskbar, all of it).

Why does autohotkey's `run, explorer.exe` not do the same thing? How can I make it start explorer.exe so I get everything back, like I did with the task manager?

UPDATE: The solution is to put `%windir%\explorer.exe`. This is my final code, and it works properly.

```
#e::
    Run, %windir%\explorer.exe
    Return
```

Comment: Making sure there are no other explorer windows open should make it start correctly

Comment: Yeah, I closed down all explorer.exe processes. Solved, I'll put the final code in my post.

Comment: Having to close Explorer just to play a game seems like a very strange situation. Are you sure that's really necessary? Also, rather than heavily modifying your local environment, have you considered using virtualization software like DOSBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try running it using `start.exe`? i.e. `Run, start explorer.exe`

Comment: That won't work. It gives: error: failed attempt to launch program or document. Action: <start explorer.exe> Params:<>
The current thread will exit.
Specifically: The system cannot find the specified file.

Comment: @AlexG, what if you give it the full path? `start %windir%\explorer.exe`

Comment: Awesome, that works! I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't. I think autohotkey runs a slightly different version of cmd and other commands than would normally be run (if I did `win+r` and typed "explorer.exe")
So I guess by typing `%windir%` first, it accesses the real thing.

Comment: @Laurent Can you explain what difference this makes to just calling Explorer.exe? Also note that start is NOT an executable (since XP IIRC), it's a function of cmd.exe.

Comment: @Deanna, to be honest I'm not completely sure, I ran into similar issues before and solved them by using `start` instead of letting it go through `cmd.exe`. One possible difference is that start.exe launches the app and exit while cmd.exe is going to wait for it to close. Usually, you'd start GUI applications with start.exe and command line app with cmd.exe.